# Alias not working for centos 7

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am trying to setup a custom monitoring for foreman using checkmk MRPE plugin. The check ( bash shell script ) works fine inside the shell however on telnet from outside i am not able to get output

The issue seems to be alias for user which involves assigning it a admin password , not working. Due to this the output is not correct.

I have added the alias in the shell script and /etc/profile however the checkmk agent is still not able to call it properly.

Any idea what i am missing

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias hammer='hammer -u admin -p XXXXXXXXXXX'
STATE_OK=0
STATE_CRITICAL=2
STATUS=`hammer capsule content synchronization-status --id 11|grep Status:|grep "Capsule is synchronized"`
RET_VAL=$?
if [ "$RET_VAL" != "0" ]
then
ERR_STATUS=`hammer capsule content synchronization-status --id 11|grep -i status|cut -d ":" -f 3`
echo "$ERR_STATUS needs to be synced."
exit $STATE_CRITICAL
else
echo "Capsule is synchronized."
exit $STATE_OK
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

aliases are best avoided, especially in scripts. Here, I'd write:

```
#!/bin/bash -
typeset -A code=([OK]=0 [WARNING]=1 [CRITICAL]=2 [UNKNOWN]=3)

hammer() {
  command hammer -u admin -p XXXXXXXXXXX "$@"
}

result=UNKNOWN
if
  status=$(
    hammer capsule content synchronization-status --id 11|
      grep 'Status:'
  )
then
  if
    [[ $status = *'Capsule is synchronized'* ]]
  then
    message='Capsule is synchronized.'
    result=OK
  else
    message="$status needs to be synced."
    result=CRITICAL
  fi
else
  message="Can't determine status."
fi

printf '%s\n' "$result - $message"
exit "${code[$result]}"
```

In any case, `/etc/profile` or `rc` files are not read by shells started to interpret scripts (except for (t)csh¹). Imagine the mess it would be if scripts behaved differently  based on which users invoked them and what alias they  had in their `~/.shellrc`.

Note that it's bad practice to pass passwords on the command line, as that's public information on a system (shows in the output of `ps -f` and can potentially end up in logs). I don't know what `hammer` is but it's likely it provide alternative safer ways to pass passwords (via env vars, file descriptors or conf files for instance), and if not would be broken by design.

---

<sup>¹  which is why you use `#! /bin/csh -f` for shebangs there, though best is to avoid (t)csh altogether for scripting at least.</sup>